# remove consecutive whitespaces but allow single whitespaces regex erlang

Tags: regex, erlang

Let us say this is the text input

```
Text = "\s\n\t\s\s\n\t\s\n\s\s Hello\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\s\s\t\t\s\t Hello \s\s\n\n\n\t\s\s\s\n\t"
```

I just want to remove the consecutive (spaces or newline or tabs) but keep the single ones and also newline followed by space should be replaced by \n... I want the output to be

```
"Hello\nHello"
```

I have tried this far

```
RemoveTrails = re:replace(Text, "(^\\s+)|(\\s+$)", "", [global,{return,list}]),
Singlenewline = re:replace(RemoveTrails, "(\\n{2,})", "\n", [global,{return,list}]),
TrimmedText = re:replace(Singlenewline, "(\\s{2,})", "\s", [global,{return,list}])
```

Which gives me the output

```
"Hello\n \t\t \t Hello"
```

I can't go further...I think there should be a simple way to achieve the expected output... please guide me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `\s` is not a valid character, so your input text is a little off. After correcting for that, however, this should do what you're looking for:

```
re:replace(Text, "([\r\n]?)\\s+", "\\1 ", [global, multiline, {return, list}]).
```

Combine with your "RemoveTrails" regex to clean any unwanted leading/trailing whitespace. Unfortunately you can't do all of it with a single regex (or maybe you can, but I wouldn't want to see it)

Comment: Well, `\s` is a valid character, but it's not a whitespace character. Don't confuse `\s` with the character code for space; it's a character *class* in regexes, one that covers spaces and tabs (and newlines in the case of multiline). Also, note how I'm not double-escaping the slashes in `[\r\n]`; it's unnecessary here.

Comment: Thanks for correcting and helping me Soup d'Campbells... But the output now is "Hello\n\n\n\nHello"...

Comment: @user27841 - I get the output " Hello\n Hello "; make sure you got everything (including the multiline option)

Comment: @user27841 - Sorry, copying from bash mutilated the command I added. The regex portion should be: `"([\r\n]?)\\s+"` (add + after \\s)

Comment: Thanks for the code... It works fine... When the input text is "Hello   Hello" or "Hello \n\n\n\n Hello" the output is "HelloHello" for both instead of "Hello Hello" and "Hello\nHello" respectively...

Comment: @user27841 - More mangling. There should be a space in the replace segment. So: `"\\1 "`

Comment: Thanks... That works fine for "Hello Hello"..but for "Hello \n\n\n\n Hello" it gives me "Hello Hello" instead of "Hello\nHello"...

Comment: Yeah, you're not going to be able to cover that case *and* remove excess space characters in a single regex. The other thing you can do is collapse repeating consecutive instances down to a single instance of the character (`"([\r\n\s])[\r\n\s]*", "\\1"`), but even then you still can't handle mixed groups easily (e.g., " \n ")